# Adding onClickLabel to compose box

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm starting out on compose and I've created a clickable box. For accessibility purposes I'm trying to add the onClickLabel, but I'm having no joy. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Please share your code along with question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look so simple.

```
Box(Modifier.fillMaxWidth().clickable { /*Call your function here*/ }) {
                Text(
                    "Simple text",
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                    modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center)
                )
                Icon(
                    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_launcher_background),
                    contentDescription = "Icon",
                    modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterEnd)
                )
            }
```

The "clicable" method can be added for all Compose layouts, for Text (lable) also.